# How does Gifmaker.org remove white halo on transparent GIFs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, animation, gif, adobe-after-effects

When I try to export with Photoshop or use other online GIF makers, they always end up with the ugly white halo. What makes Gifmaker.org so different, and how can I replicate it in Photoshop or Adobe Effects?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that GIF has no alpha channel that can show semi-transparent colors. For that you would need to save as PNG24. With a GIF, antialiasing inevitably comes with a halo.

If you don’t want antialiased edges in a transparent GIF, then you should set the setting *Matte* to *None* in the *Save for web* Panel.  (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>).

[image]